# Replace subset of Python dataframe based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have 2 dfs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Friend1':['Amy','Bob','Charlie'],'Friend2':['Dan','Ellie','Fred'],'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})

    Friend1 Friend2 a   b   c
0   Amy     Dan     1   4   7
1   Bob     Ellie   2   5   8
2   Charlie Fred    3   6   9

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Friend1:['Zack','Yuna'],'Friend2':['Bob','Charlie'], 'b':[100,200], 'c':[300,400]})

    Friend1 Friend2 b   c
0   Zack    Bob     100 300
1   Yuna    Charlie 200 400
```

How do I replace whats in df2 into df so that the new df becomes:

```
    Friend1 Friend2 a   b   c
0   Amy     Dan     1   4   7
1   Bob             2   100 300
2   Charlie         3   200 400
```

Note that I need Friend 2 to be empty for Bob and Charlie in the new df.

I have tried something like

```
df.loc[df[df.Friend1.isin(['Bob','Charlie'])].index,'b':'c'] = df2.drop(['Friend1','Friend2'],axis=1)
```

But it does not work. Help!

Comment: Why do you need df2?

Comment: Sorry, the new df values were wrong for Bob and Charlie. Have corrected it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might ultimately want to use `df.update`. First, re-index your two dataframes:

```
df=df.set_index('Friend1')
df2=df2.set_index('Friend2')
```

Then update df according to information in df2:

```
df.update(df2)
```

Given that you need Friend 2 to be empty for Bob and Charlie in the new df, you can use:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(['Bob','Charlie']),'Friend2']=None
```

Gives you the output:

```
        Friend2  a      b      c
Friend1                         
Amy         Dan  1    4.0    7.0
Bob        None  2  100.0  300.0
Charlie    None  3  200.0  400.0
```

If you cannot reindex,then try:

```
df.loc[df['Friend1'].isin(['Bob','Charlie']),'Friend2']=None
df.loc[df['Friend1'].isin(['Bob','Charlie']),['b','c']]=df2.loc[:,['b','c']].values
```

gives you the same output. But it depends on how your original dataframes look like, the codes are not so dynamic as `df.update`!

Comment: Sorry my new df was wrong! I forgot to change the values for Bob and Charlie on columns b and c!

Comment: I modified my answer, could you try now? And let me know please!

Comment: I can't do it because my index values have duplicates, which are now shown in the sample here =(

Comment: The sample you show here can definitely be re-indexed (I tried with your df and df2 and it worked). I can provide answers without the use of reindexing (see edited), but it all depends on how your original dataframe look like; I can only make sure that it works on you sample dataframes.

Comment: Works great. I just needed the .values at the end to make my code work! Thank you!